# Gradually change image with CSS (wipe transition)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a weird question. It is weird, because it will be really hard for me to explain what I mean. I realize, that I could get some negative feedback, but got no other place to ask.

What I am searching for is a technique in CSS (or if not possible, then also JavaScript) to gradually change image on hover. I don't want it to fade out or change the whole image at once. What I want, is to have an image, and when I hover it with my mouse, the hovered part of image changes, and the more I hover my image, the more I can see of the other image. I hope this description is enough. I am sorry, but I have no idea how is this called.

I made something similar of what I am thinking here (https://jsbin.com/xurokogicu/edit?html,css,output)
but this is on scroll, I want this to happen when I hover image with my mouse.

Hope you understand anything I am saying here,

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Here are two pictures to better understand my idea. The black line represents that somewhere on that line (vertically) is mouse cursor. If I hover my mouse on the left, the black line moves to left and reveals part of other image. So basically at first there is this monkey picture and then, wherever I hover, appears that black line which reveals other image on right side.

[image]

[image]

EDIT2:
Guys we have found a live example of what I meant: [jpegmini.com](http://jpegmini.com)
But with different images.
Now what I am asking is how can I do it, or how is it called, because my question stands unanswered.
 I would also change the name of the title for others, who are searching for this.

EDIT3 :
WE HAVE FOUND AN ANSWER, this is exactly what I was looking for:

JS

```
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
img = new Image();         // image to show

img.onload = start;
img.src = "link to img";

function start() {
  c.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var r = c.getBoundingClientRect(),
        x = e.clientX - r.left;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height); 
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, x, c.height,  0, 0, x, c.height); 
    ctx.fillRect(x, 0, 5, c.height); 
  };

}
```

CSS

```
#c {
  background: url(link to other img); 
  background-size: cover;
  }
```

HTML

```
<canvas id=c width=620 height=400></canvas>
```

Comment: So the effect should look something like a [scratch ticket](https://www.google.com/search?q=scratch+ticket&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)?

Comment: I can't see any effect in the image you have sent

Comment: @IsraGab You have to scroll the output tab. Scrolling replaces the bunny with the chimp.

Comment: No problem. For anyone else, searching for "scratch ticket CSS' finds this example: https://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/gM632/

Comment: This is almost identical to your request: http://codepen.io/curthusting/pen/fkCzh. I suspect you could tweak this so it doesn't require a click, but just events on the hover

Comment: Thank you guys, but I was thinking of a little bit something different. It would go as in my example in a straight line, and once I hover part of the image, that part of the other image reveals. I will add to my post two pictures, hope they will help to understand more clearly.

Comment: I think you mean something like on jpegmini.com but with different images

Comment: Yes, exactly like that! Only instead of text boxes that are changing, I would like to change images. Yes. Does anyone know how is that called or which technique to use?

Comment: This is called a wipe transition. Added it to the title.

Answer (score 5):

I would use a canvas + CSS for this. This is because it will give you full control over mouse movements as well as providing a simple way to introduce bar and different types of wipes (diagonal, custom etc.) if you would like that later on.

- Define the background image as CSS for the canvas element
- Draw in top image clipped to mouse position

### Example

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
    img = new Image();         // image to show

img.onload = start;
img.src = "//i.imgur.com/mS4R13a.png";

function start() {
  c.onmousemove = function(e) {
    var r = this.getBoundingClientRect(),
        x = e.clientX - r.left;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);                     // clear canvas for new draw
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, x, c.height,  0, 0, x, c.height);  // clip and draw image to x
    ctx.fillRect(x, 0, 5, c.height);                            // draw a thin black bar
  };
}
```

```css
#c {
  background: url(//i.imgur.com/GQ6xVAT.png); 
  background-size: cover;
  }
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=620 height=400></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

To create the effect shown in your jsBin demo, which is "slide" on scroll, you could try this pure CSS approach to do it:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
  border:1px solid #CCC;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .step {
  border:1px dashed rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  flex:1;
  position: relative;
  z-index:2;
}

.container .newimg {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/) fixed no-repeat 9px 9px;
  position: absolute;
  height:100%; width:100%;
  bottom:0; left:0;
  z-index:1;
  transition:bottom .3s;
}

.container .step:nth-of-type(1):hover ~ .newimg {
  bottom: 25%;
}
.container .step:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ .newimg {
  bottom: 50%;
}
.container .step:nth-of-type(3):hover ~ .newimg {
  bottom: 75%;
}
.container .step:nth-of-type(4):hover ~ .newimg {
  bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="newimg"></div>
</div>
```

**Logic / Explanation:**

Basically we have a container with an image, inside it there are "steps" that when hovered, will alter another child that contains another image. The second image is has `fixed` attachment to create a parallax effect.

Of course this could be smoother by adding more steps, to simplify this you could create a SASS loop to calculate each step:

```
$steps: 10;
@for $i from 1 through $steps {
  .container .step:nth-of-type(#{$i}):hover ~ .newimg {
    bottom: $i * 1/$steps * 100%;
  }
}
```

The output of that will look like this:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/g/400/200/);
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container .step {
  border: 1px dashed rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.container .newimg {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/) fixed no-repeat 9px 9px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: .3s;
}

.container .step:nth-of-type(1):hover ~ .newimg {
  bottom: 10%;
}

.container .step:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ .newimg {
  bottom: 20%;
}

.container .step:nth-of-type(3):hover ~ .newimg {
  bottom: 30%;
}

.container .step:nth-of-type(4):hover ~ .newimg {
  bottom: 40%;
}

.container .step:nth-of-type(5):hover ~ .newimg {
  bottom: 50%;
}

.container .step:nth-of-type(6):hover ~ .newimg {
  bottom: 60%;
}

.container .step:nth-of-type(7):hover ~ .newimg {
  bottom: 70%;
}

.container .step:nth-of-type(8):hover ~ .newimg {
  bottom: 80%;
}

.container .step:nth-of-type(9):hover ~ .newimg {
  bottom: 90%;
}

.container .step:nth-of-type(10):hover ~ .newimg {
  bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- emmet code: .step*10 -->
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="step"></div>
  <div class="newimg"></div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle with SCSS/SASS: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/q4Lye8he/

jsFiddle for 4 steps only: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/e92c6avj/

The only **drawback** to this is having to create extra HTML tags for each step.

Answer (score 0):

The term you're looking for is 'cross fade'.  There's an example [here](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/) that works on hover, though I'm not sure how you'd do it for just the part of the image that you're hovering over (this fades the whole thing on hover).  If you want it to cross fade only where the mouse is, you'd probably have to go to the Canvas api to erase pixels, but I'm not sure.

HTML:

```
  <div id="cf">
    <img class="bottom" src="/images/Cirques.jpg" />
    <img class="top" src="/images/Clown%20Fish.jpg" />
  </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#cf {
  position:relative;
  height:281px;
  width:450px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#cf img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please assemble a stacksnippet?