# Wipe-in effect using Javascript and Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am making a math teaching web page (URL below) and want to use JavaScript to create a wipe-in effect of a Canvas drawing.  As you can see on my page, I have drawn a series of rectangles in a pattern.  When the student enters the correct answer, I want to draw Fig. 5 using a wipe-in effect.  What would be the best way to do that?

My thought at first would be to create a function that draws the entire pattern, then cover it with a white box that decreases in size, but I would surmise that doing it that way would cause a fluttering effect rather than a clean wipe.

Any ideas for how best to accomplish this?  Thanks in advance for the help!

URL of page: http://collinmath.com/Lessons/blocks.html
URL of Javascript: http://collinmath.com/Lessons/blocks.js

Comment: firstly, I highly recommend not using wipe in effects unless you have a really good reason, but something simpler. Secondly, learn about using masking canvases :)

Comment: Like [automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36563128/1693593) or [manually](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36663873/1693593) ?